# JXL Column Span

Tags: jxl

I have multiple rows in my excel, where contents are small except the top row.
Just in order to insert a big title in the top row, i would not like the width of subsequent rows' to be impacted.
Is there a way i can span the content in the top row over multiple columns and without affecting the width of subsequent rows.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, by using the WritableSheet.mergeCells method.

For example:

```
WritableWorkbook w = Workbook.createWorkbook(outputStream);
WritableSheet s = w.createSheet("MySheet", 0);
int row = 0;

WritableCell titleCell = new Label(0, row, "Hello World");
s.addCell(titleCell);
s.mergeCells(0, row, 13, row);
```

This has the effect of making the first row be 13 cells wide, and will not effect the cell widths of the subsequent rows. Note, this will allow you to merge rows but this will not work. The correct way to change the row height is by:

```
/* Row heights are in 20ths of a point */
int fontPointSize = 16;
int rowHeight = (int) ((1.5d * fontPointSize) * 20);
s.setRowView(row, rowHeight, false);
```

Answer (score 2):

This is possible, play around with this. Hope it will help you.

```
int col1 = 0;
int col2 = 2;
int row1 = 0;
int row2 = 0;

WritableWorkbook workbook = Workbook.createWorkbook(outputStream);
WritableSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("MySheet", 0);
sheet.mergeCells(col1,row1,col2,row2); 
//This makes the cell at row1 and col1 span the next two cells
//Write content at the marge cell
sheet.addCell(new Label(col1,row1,"Content here"));
```

References:
[first reference](http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net/resources/javadocs/2_6_10/docs/jxl/write/WritableSheet.html) and [socond reference](http://bethecoder.com/applications/tutorials/excel/jexcel-api/how-to-merge-cells-in-excel-spreadsheet.html)